# Prove that there exists infinitely many integers $(y,z)$ satisfying the equation $y^4=z^{31}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Prove that there exists infinitely many integers $(y,z)$ satisfying the equation $y^4=z^{31}$.

This question came in WB RMO 2015 in a different way. **There the problem asked to prove that there exists infinitely many integers $(x,y,z)$ satisfying the equation $x^3+y^4=z^{31}$**
I am trying to solve this in a different way, different from the official solution

On assuming $x=0$, we get $y^4=z^{31}$. Now if we can prove what I wrote in the question, are we not done? Please help me to prove that. This question is already there on stackexchange, but I want to prove it in this way.

Comment: I'm sure they meant positive integers $(x,y,z)$

Comment: In the official paper, it was not mentioned

Comment: [Here](http://www.cheenta.com/2015/12/06/regional-math-olympiad-rmo-2015-west-bengal/) is the original list of questions, which specifies *positive* integers.

Comment: If you were to allow one of them, specifically $x$, to be zero... then the answer is trivial  Take $y=n^{31k}$ and $z=(n)^{4k}$ for any choice of $n,k\in\Bbb N$.  Then $y^{4}=z^{31}$ and we are done.

Comment: http://www.isical.ac.in/~rmo/papers/rmo/rmo-2015-3.pdf

Comment: the official paper from isi website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y=k^{31},z=k^4,k\in\Bbb Z$$
But they probably meant $x,y,z>0$ in the original question, since this appears too simple.